Retrieve original url within axios request
I have a middleware that intercepts every request. Some of them have params like this /:id/:q.
but I can not retrieve that original string from url inside axios Incoming message because it seemingly contains only for example /2/boo. Is there any way to do that ?
I tried to search req object from axios

are you expecting to see /:id/:q ??? why? what use would that be?

What do you really mean by "original string"?

@JaromandaX I need that string to record stats with prometheus. already resolved the issue. it was req.route.path

The original string from /foo/bar/:id/:type is located in req.route.path

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
